# Project needs assistance with header files

Tags: c, header

I am currently working on a small project that runs off of a completely custom built version on linux. I have a copy of all the header files that are in /usr/include on the customer OS however I really dont get along with that OS so i want to carry on the project from my fedora box. I tried creating a new directory in the fedora's /usr/include however it throws up a hissy fit everytime it comes to compile. Is there a way that I can tell the compiler to go to another directory for header files, e.g. /usr/include2?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`-I /usr/include2` (though `/usr/include2` is of course very bad name for this purpose).

Comment: yeah i get that its a bad name but im just not sure how good my wording was haha! so gcc -I

Answer (score 1):

See [compiler's `-I` option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-I-886). It allows you to specify where to look for header files.

Comment: for some reason that still hates me!

Comment: that hates me! I have the entire include library from the other OS which has alot of the same named .h files that are completely different on the inside!